# Is there a way to make `docker` output the HTTP requests sent to the daemon, just like it's possible with `kubectl` and the API server?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I've been using `kubectl -vvvv ...` a lot to learn about the different HTTP requests sent to the API server for different commands.

However, I cannot seem to find a way of achieving the same with `docker`.

In particular, I've considered `docker --debug ...`, but e.g. `docker --debug ps` just displays the normal output.

How can I make `docker` output the HTTP requests sent to the daemon?

Answer (score 4):

> How can I make docker output the HTTP requests sent to the daemon?

You can't, but you can set up a proxy server between the client and the docker daemon so that you can see the requests. The `socat` tool is useful for this. Set up a proxy by running:

```
socat -v unix-listen:/tmp/docker.sock,fork unix-connect:/var/run/docker.sock
```

And then point `docker` at the proxy:

```
docker -H unix:///tmp/docker.sock ps
```

As you make requests with `docker`, you'll see the requests and replies in the output from the `socat` command.

(You can set the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable if you get tired of typing the `-H ...` command line option.)

Comment: Thank you, @larsks - Indeed this is preferable to using Wireshark! :)